# SEO changes in wordpress after permalink changes

Tags: seo

I have installed wordpress in a sub-directory called blg in my root folder. Also, I have served the website from the root following the method given in this [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).
My question is, if in future I am planning to create my own website at root and giving a link for blog to the wordpress site in the directory, then my permalink are going to be changed. If this gonna affect my SEO anyhow.
Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the authority of your website you will see a massive disruption in your rankings dude to 301's; ultimately the rankings will return to normal in a few weeks. (this of course depends on your distribution of 'link juice'). The new site you are creating will not suffer as you are doing nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If Wordpress is already in it's own directory, this isn't an issue. The permalinks will remain the same in the /blg/ folder.